# How would I remake the :lower() in lua

Tags: lua

How would I make a string meta table
So I can do

```
local test = "HeLlO HoW ARE YoU"
print(test:lowercase())
```

But I don't want to use the default `:lower()`
Or `string.lower(str) / lower(str)`

The meta table for string?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to rename the method `lowercase`, just do `string.lowercase=string.lower`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, appending a new method to `string` is another possibility. For instance, here is a method that returns the same string.

```
function string.identity (self)
   local ret = {}
   for i=1,self:len() do
      local c = self:sub(i, i)
      table.insert(ret, c)
   end
   return table.concat(ret)
end
local test = "HeLlO HoW ARE YoU"
print(test:identity())
```

Appending new methods to built-in objects, or modifying existing ones, has the disadvantage that if you're using external libraries those libraries could override your changes. So as rule of thumb I tend not to do it, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

## Just modifying `string`

Nothing easier than that.

```
string.lowercase = string.lower
```

---

EDIT: As user3125367 pointed out (thanks for that), my second answer doesn't work because `setmetatable` doesn't work with strings. While one could make it work by wrapping the string in a table and redirecting the method calls, that seems pretty inefficient and like something only a Ruby programmer would actually do.

---

In the end the best advice I can give you is: *Don't*

Lua is built the way it is and adding custom aliases will just confuse people reading your code. If I saw `:uppercase()` somewhere in a codebase, I'd assume it behaves differently from `:upcase()` in some way and waste looking for what it really does.

Comment: If _ sets a metatable with only *lowercase* __index key in it, then you can't write _"":upper(), since *upper* is not there. I guess second block should be read as `_"hElLo WoRlD":lowercase() --> hello world`?

Comment: Second note, more important is that setmetatable() doesn't work with string argument (but debug.setmetatable() does). Primitive types, strings included, have exactly one metatable on *all* values of such type. Setting a completely different __index will render all library code useless. Setting compatible __index can be done one time at program start, thus there is no need for _ at all.